# slow stored proc query

Tags: sql-server

I have tables

```
Book: 
Id | Name |  ...

UrlRecord:  
Id | EntityId | Entityname | Slug  >> to store id-less url for many other tables like Category | Book | BookChapter...
```

So the data is **huge**.

EntityId=> contains Id in other table like bookid, categoryid, chapterId...

```
Id EntityId    Entityname        Slug
1     2        Category      truyen-tranh
2     2        BookChapter    chapter-one
```

....

SearchBookDetails stored procedure:

```
SELECT p.Source,
    (SELECT Slug from UrlRecord url where EntityName = 'Category' and EntityId = (SELECT top(1) CategoryId from Book_Category_Mapping bc where bc.BookId = p.Id)
    ) as CategorySeName

FROM   ....
```

the performance is very slow, up to 22 seconds if I have the CategorySeName clause above because it's a heavy query.

However, i don't know how to improve the performance and still get the CategorySeName value return  like above.

Comment: Did you try to get a query plan? You most likely need an index on (EntityId, EntityName)

Comment: What does C# have to do with this question?

Comment: Are there indices on the tables that contain all the columns used in the `WHERE` clauses in the order they are used in the `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: And EAV tables like your URL record are a design smell. It is a poor technique to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your  problem is the correlated subnquery. This is an extremely poor technique that changes your select statment into a what is basically a cursor and runs it row-by-agonizing-row. Never use them if you have a large data set. Use a derived table or a CTE or a temp table instead.

Answer (score 0):

You use EntityId to point to N other tables, like bookid, categoryid, chapterId.
You're table design is wrong, it's actually impossible to set a foreign key.

It is wrong, because that way you cannot enforce foreign-keys.

And much worse, this will result in slow query performance, because there has been no index created automagically, as it does when you create a foreign key.

The query optimizer will thus come up with a very ugly execution plan, which explains why it is that slow.

If you must have an object id, you can createa a view and do:

```
COALESCE(bookid, categoryid, chapterId) AS EntityId
```

but I very much doubt object_id, or EntityId as you call it, is of any use to you that way.

**PS:**

string comparison instead of using an id is always a bad idea

```
where EntityName = 'Category'
```

combining those two antipatterns is an especially good idea.

Comment: FKs do not create indexes automatically in SQL Server. THey must have indexes created manually.

Comment: this table Urlrecord is a data entity only, not related to any other tables. Actually, i'm using http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/ for my project.